# Update sonata admin by Composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin

I'm trying to update sonata admin by using composer but I have this error

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[dev-master].
- sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.x-dev requires sonata-project/admin-bundle ~2.2,>=2.2.9 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[2.2.x-dev, 2.3.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: sonata-project/admin-bundle[dev-master, 2.2.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: sonata-project/admin-bundle[dev-master, 2.3.x-dev].
- Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[2.2.x-dev].
```

Here is a sample of my `composer.json` :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.2.x-dev"
},
```

I'm using this command :

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/user-bundle#2.3.x-dev) to see the requirements.

*You're error message says you should choose which version to use, because the `user-bundle 2.2` needs a `sonata-admin v2.2`. 
 
 In reading packagist I can see that `userbundle 2.3` is ok with your `sonata-admin v2.3`*

I think you just have to update the `user-bundle` from `2.2` to `2.3`

*Or maybe will it be more safe for futur, to fix your package version instead of using `dev-master`.
 If there is an update, it breaks everything like now.*

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "dev-master",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master", // Actually 2.3
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master", 
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.3.x-dev"    // <----- HERE
},
```